# React axios loading on demand

Tags: php

For example, a bulletin board that has obtained data through axios

Title: {itme.title}

Content: {item.description}

If implemented like this

When the view is first viewed, only the title: and content: are visible because of the data retrieval time.

How do you usually deal with this?

Does the loading window show until data is received or is there another way?

I'm new to react, anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are 2 options:

First, is to not render anything until you have the data, like:

```js
let content = `Title: {item.title}
Content: {item.description}`;
return item ? content : <></>;
```

Second is to render some [placeholder content](https://semantic-ui.com/elements/placeholder.html) or a [spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loader-spinner). In this case the example is the same, just replace `<></>` with something interesting for users to look at.